# How to use Telegram API for Android

Tags: android, api, telegram

i want to use the Telegram API to create an Android app that works with Telegram data.

I already registered a new app and i have an api_id and an api_hash.

The problem is that i don't know what do to next, i tried to read the documentation but i find it really messy, it just jumps from create the app to authentication but doesn't explain how to setup android project and other necessary things.

I already tried to search some android project as this:

https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram

But when i start it simply doesn't works and send NDK errors.

Does someone can explain me the steps to do next?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site.

Comment: I know, but i really don't know what to do next and i would understand what to do next to accomplish my goal

Comment: Please learn simple Android application before create this massive project

Comment: Once again, Stack Overflow is **not a tutorial site**.